# What is making me teleport instead of die?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth, the-binding-of-isaac-afterbirth

So, I'm playing Afterbirth and twice in a row on the same floor (once at Krampus and once in a random room) I have been teleported to a different room on taking fatal damage. I looked up all my items and I have no idea what's causing this.

I have: x-ray vision, large odd mush, box of stuff, mom's perfume, lunch, boom, and my trinket is host hat.

Comment: Were you teleported to a different (random) room, or the room you were in prior to the room you died in?

Answer (score 10):

As I read your question I noticed that you said your trinket was "Host Hat", which is actually [an item](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Host_Hat). What you probably were holding was the ["Cursed Skull" trinket](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Cursed_Skull), which teleports you to another room if you are damaged to half a red heart.

Comment: Oh yes, this is probably it. Your second link is to a German wiki, FYI.